# List<string> is not updated back to ListBox's ItemsSource?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I'm new to WPF. I have a `List<string>` as a source for my `ListBox's ItemsSource`. Initially, the `ListBox` shows all the `Items` in my `List<string>` OK. However, after trying adding some string to my `List<string>`, the `ListBox` doesn't update the changes. I'm using `Binding` to bind the data (behind) with the `ListBox` (view), here is my code:

```
//Code behind
public MainWindow: Window {
   public MainWindow(){
      InitializeComponent();
      Items = new List<string>(){"1","2","3"};//after loaded, all these values are displayed OK in my ListBox.
      DataContext = this;
      //Try clicking on a button to add new value
      button1.Click += (s,e) => {
         Items.Add("4");//But my ListBox stays the same without any update/changes.
      };
   }
   public List<string> Items {get;set;}
}
//XAML
<ListBox ItemsSource={Binding Items}/>
```

Could you please point out what I'm doing wrong here and give me a solution? Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: Change your `List<string>` to an `ObservableCollection<string>`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you had read the [documentation of `ItemsSource`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.itemscontrol.itemssource.aspx) you would already know what is wrong.

> [...]
>
> This example shows how to create and bind to a collection that derives from the [`ObservableCollection<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms668604.aspx) class, which is a collection class that provides notifications when items get added or removed.

Answer (score 1):

you should try ObservableCollection instead because it's 
*Represents a dynamic data collection that provides notifications when items get added, removed, or when the whole list is refreshed.*

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication3.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <Button Click="Button_Click" Content="Button" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="441,289,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75"/>
        <ListBox HorizontalAlignment="Left" ItemsSource="{Binding MyList,Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Name="lstbox" Height="296" Margin="21,23,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="209"/>

    </Grid>
</Window>

using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;

namespace WpfApplication3
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        private ObservableCollection<string> _myList = new ObservableCollection<string>(new List<string>(){"1","2","3"});
        int i = 3;  

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.DataContext = this;  
        }

        private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            MyList.Add(i++.ToString());  
        }
        public ObservableCollection<string> MyList
        {
            get { return _myList; }
            set { _myList = value; }
        }
    }
}
```